# Given a set N of integers and an integer y, determine if there two elements exist in N whose absolute difference is equal to y

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I came across this question and I am stuck on this. It says,

> Given a set N of integers and an integer y, determine if there exit
>   two elements in N whose  absolute difference is equal to y and also
>   print those numbers. The algorithm should take  O(n lg n) time.
>   Justify why your algorithm runs in O(n lg n) time. e.g. Let N= 3 , 7,
>   2, 1, 4, 10 y = 1 there are three pairs of elements in N whose
>   absolute difference is 1 Pair 1 = |3 - 2| = |-1| = 1 Pair 2 = |3 - 4|=
>   |-1| = 1 Pair 3 = |2 -1| = 1

I tried this in C++ as follows, but it does not handle all boundary cases like if y=8 for above example, it does not print anything however it should print (2,10).

```
vector<int> printPairs(vector<int> N1, vector<int> N2, int y){
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    vector<int> result;
    while (a < N1.size() && b < N2.size()){
        if (N1[a] < N2[b]){
            result.push_back(N1[a]);
            if (abs(N1[a] - N2[b]) == y)
                cout << "(" << N1[a] << "," << N2[b] << ")" << endl;
            a++;
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(N2[b]);
            if (abs(N1[a] - N2[b]) == y)
                cout << "(" << N1[a] << "," << N2[b] << ")" << endl;
            b++;
        }
    }
    while (a < N1.size())
        result.push_back(N1[a++]);
    while (b < N2.size()){
        result.push_back(N2[b++]);
    }
    return result;
}
vector <int> getPairs(vector<int> N, int y){
    if (N.size() == 1)
        return N;
    vector <int> firstHalf = getPairs(vector<int>(N.begin(), N.begin() + N.size() / 2), y);
    vector <int> secondHalf = getPairs(vector<int>(N.begin() + ceil(N.size() / 2), N.end()), y);
    return printPairs(firstHalf, secondHalf, y);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use std::set container.

Time complexity of std::set::find() is O(logN).

Calling N times find() costs you O(NlogN).

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
  std::set<int> values = {3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 10};
  int y = 1;
  for (int elem : values) {
    if (values.find(elem + y) != values.end()) {
      std::cout << elem << " " << elem + y << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Another algorithm:

1. sort elements (NlogN)
2. for each element use binary search (logN per search query).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> values = {3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 10};
  int y = 1;
  std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
  for (int i = 0; i + 1 < values.size(); ++i) {
    if (std::binary_search(
          values.begin() + i + 1, values.end(), values[i] + y)) {
      std::cout << values[i] << " " << values[i] + y << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Or you can simplify step 2 to O(N), by using two pointers idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> values = {3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 10};
  int y = 1;
  std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
  int l = 0, r = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i + 2 < 2 * values.size(); ++i) {
    if (r + 1 < values.size() &&
        values[r] - values[l] <= y) {
      ++r;
    } else {
      ++l;
    }
    if (values[l] + y == values[r]) {
      std::cout << values[l] << " " << values[r] << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Total complexity will be the same (but the algorithm will be a little bit faster): O(NlogN) + O(N) = O(NlogN)

Comment: That was really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are cheating: You neglected the cost of putting the numbers into a container, which is `O(n log n)` for the set! Effectively, you are sorting the input first, which is also the approach I would have taken.

Comment: That is not cheating. The cost of sorting is O(n log n). This will simply add in to the cost of searching which is n times log n too. thus overall cost will be 2*n log n which is in asymptotic notation equal to O(n log n).